# How to increase width of slide out

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

I want to change how far this slideout panel goes in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mb6uw0ty/1/). I used the code from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egUHv/16/) for this. In that one, if I change the width of slideit and the left close setting to 200 instead of 100, the width increases and works fine. But if I do the same in mine, the panel disappears. I'm guessing I didn't change something correctly when converting it to the left side. Can anyone explain how to increase the width so the panel slides out farther?

```
    <style>
    div#slideit {position: fixed; top: 100px; left:0px; margin: 0px; padding: 20px 0px 0px; color:#fff; background:#5681b4; list-style: none; z-index:9999; width: 100px; border-radius:0px 30px 30px 5px}
    div#slideit .slideit-btn {background:#5681b4; border-radius:0px 10px 10px 0px; position:absolute; top:10px; left:90px; width:40px; height:70px; display:block; cursor:pointer;}
    div#slideit .slideitspan {width:100px; margin:4px 2px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; color:#FFF;}
    .vertical-text {
     font-size:18px; 
     transform: rotate(90deg);
     transform-origin: left top 0;
     position:absolute; top: 10px; left:34px;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="slideit">
     <div class="slideit-btn"> <span class="vertical-text"></span></div>
     <div class="slideitspan">You can now easily create banners, configure them as you like, link them to anywhere you want, like to products, categories, any page of your store or any other website and display them on various areas of your store, for example the front page. Learn more on the mini template system usage page </div>
    </div>   

    <script>
    $(function() {
     $.fn.ToggleSlide = function() {
         return this.each(function() {
             //$(this).css('position', 'absolute');

             if(parseInt($(this).css('left')) < 0) {
                 $(this).animate({ 'left' : '0px' }, 120, function() {
                 $(".vertical-text").text("Close");
                     //$(this).css('position', 'relative');
                 });
             }
             else {
                 $(this).animate({ 'left' : '-100px' }, 120, function() {
                 $(".vertical-text").text("Open");
                     //$(this).css('position', 'relative');
                 });
             }
         });
     };

    $('#slideit').ToggleSlide();

     $(".slideit-btn").bind("click", function() {
         $('#slideit').ToggleSlide();
     });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very straight-forward. Increase the widths of html elements

```
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
#slideit, #slideit .slideitspan{width:300px;}
#slideit .slideitspan{padding: 30px;}
#slideit .slideit-btn{left: initial; right: -32px;}
```

and then adjust the offset applied by js to the same amount:

```
$(this).animate({ 'left' : '-300px' }, 120, function() {...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2c7rzm3q/

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I don't understand all of the changes but can you tell me why they are needed in my code and not the original? Is it because of the changes I made, like removing the list? I'm just curious.

Comment: I just changed the width and offset. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Your jsfiddle has the extra 4 lines you mentioned above. I assumed they had to be added. Did you just add them to be more clear? I've never seen a statement like *{box-sizing: border-box;} so I thought it was required. If the 4 lines can be merged into the existing code, would that be more efficient, from a coding perspective, or does it now matter with css?

Comment: box-sizing statement you see is used in popular frameworks like bootstrap, it's a way of simplifying math when adding padding to elements